AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'
I try to shift Mnist image by one pixel in each direction(up, down, left, right) and add these shifted image into the training set. But the result always shows the same error. The following is the code
from scipy.ndimage import shift
import pandas as pd

def shift_image(image, shift_x, shift_y):
    image = image.reshape(28,28)
    shifted_image = shift(image, shift_x, shift_y)
    return shifted_image.reshape(-1)

X_train_expansion = X_train.copy()
y_train_expansion = y_train.copy()
for shift_x, shift_y in ((0,1), (0,-1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)):
    for image, label in zip(np.array(X_train), y_train):
        X_train_expansion = pd.concat(X_train_expansion, shift_image(image, shift_x, shift_y))
        y_train_expansion.append(label)

[AttributeError image]
Can anyone tell me why this happen and what the possible solutions will be?

Your current approach involves nested loops and reshaping, which can be quite slow. Instead of using np.append within loops, consider using numpy.roll for efficient pixel shifting.
Using numpy.roll, you can achieve the desired image shifts using numpy.roll. Here’s an example of how to do it:
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift
from keras.datasets import mnist

# Load MNIST dataset
(x_train, y_train), _ = mnist.load_data()

def shift_image(image, shift_x, shift_y):
    return np.roll(image, (shift_x, shift_y), axis=(0, 1)).reshape(-1)

# Create shifted copies for each direction
X_train_expansion = []
y_train_expansion = []

for shift_x, shift_y in ((0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)):
    for image, label in zip(x_train, y_train):
        shifted_image = shift_image(image, shift_x, shift_y)
        X_train_expansion.append(shifted_image)
        y_train_expansion.append(label)

X_train_expansion = np.array(X_train_expansion)
y_train_expansion = np.array(y_train_expansion)


Hi, pandas has removed the append method from its library; therefore, it cannot be used to add rows in dataframes anymore. (X_train_expansion.append(...))

According to the error message, the problem is with the output variable in the shift function.  While it occurs several layers down it appears that output is an int, while output.shape indicates it should be an array (a class of objects that has a shape attribute).
Looking at the shift docs, I see the signature is:
shift(input, shift, output=None, ...)

where output is supposed to be an array.  shift can be a scalar, or a sequence.
You call it with:
shift(image, shift_x, shift_y)

Your 3rd argument is shift_y, not a output array.
the fix?  Calling the shift function with the right kinds of arguments, the kinds specified in the documentation.
shift(image, (shift_x, shift_y))


Thank you, I see what is happening now, and you are right. I checked shift API for many times but did not see the parentheses :(
